# Eclipse Expressions Error because of Code

Tags: eclipse

Yesterday it was working fine, but now the "expressions" pane in Eclipse will not display any useful information while debugging, but gives the error shown in the photo. I have looked around for an answer but I can't find anything useful. Does anyone know how to fix this? I tried debugging a different program and then it worked, so it must have something to do with my code I guess(?).

Details:

- Eclipse Helios
- Windows 7 on HP635 laptop
- variables DO exist as can be seen in variables pane
- Restarting Eclipse doesn't help
- Restarting computer doesn't help
- Closing and reopening expressions pane doesn't help
- Clearing expressions pane doesn't help

[image]

My Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Driver {

    private List<Integer>[] duplicateLists = new ArrayList[5];
    private List<Integer>[] lists = new ArrayList[5];

    private final int NUM_ALGORITHMS = 5;

    private boolean flag = false; //testing only
    private int calls = 0; // testing only

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Driver().run();
    }


    private void run() {
        printHeaders();
        createLists();
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ALGORITHMS; ++i) {
            resetDuplicates();
            switch (i) {
            case 0:
                System.out.print("|               | In order      |");
                System.out.println(selectionSort(duplicateLists[0]));
                System.out.println("|               |---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+");
                System.out.print("|               | Reverse Order |");
                System.out.println(selectionSort(duplicateLists[1]));
                System.out.println("|               |---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+");
                System.out.print("|   SELECTION   | Random 1      |");
                System.out.println(selectionSort(duplicateLists[2]));
                System.out.println("|               |---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+");
                System.out.print("|               | Random 2      |");
                System.out.println(selectionSort(duplicateLists[3]));
                System.out.println("|               |---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+");
                System.out.print("|               | Partial Order |");
                System.out.println(selectionSort(duplicateLists[4]));
                System.out.println("+===============+===============+===============+===============+===============+");
                break;
            case 1:
                System.out.print("|               | In order      |");
                System.out.println(insertionSort(duplicateLists[0]));
                System.out.println("|               |---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+");
                System.out.print("|               | Reverse Order |");
                System.out.println(insertionSort(duplicateLists[1]));
                System.out.println("|               |---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+");
                System.out.print("|   INSERTION   | Random 1      |");
                System.out.println(insertionSort(duplicateLists[2]));
                System.out.println("|               |---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+");
                System.out.print("|               | Random 2      |");
                System.out.println(insertionSort(duplicateLists[3]));
                System.out.println("|               |---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+");
                System.out.print("|               | Partial Order |");
                System.out.println(insertionSort(duplicateLists[4]));
                System.out.println("+===============+===============+===============+===============+===============+");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.print("|               | In order      |");
                System.out.println(bubbleSort(duplicateLists[0]));
                System.out.println("|               |---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+");
                System.out.print("|               | Reverse Order |");
                System.out.println(bubbleSort(duplicateLists[1]));
                System.out.println("|               |---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+");
                System.out.print("|    BUBBLE     | Random 1      |");
                System.out.println(bubbleSort(duplicateLists[2]));
                System.out.println("|               |---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+");
                System.out.print("|               | Random 2      |");
                System.out.println(bubbleSort(duplicateLists[3]));
                System.out.println("|               |---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+");
                System.out.print("|               | Partial Order |");
                System.out.println(bubbleSort(duplicateLists[4]));
                System.out.println("+===============+===============+===============+===============+===============+");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.print("|               | In order      |");
                System.out.println(mergeSort(duplicateLists[0]));
                System.out.println("|               |---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+");
                System.out.print("|               | Reverse Order |");
                System.out.println(mergeSort(duplicateLists[1]));
                System.out.println("|               |---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+");
                System.out.print("|     MERGE     | Random 1      |");
flag = true;
                System.out.println(mergeSort(duplicateLists[2]));
flag = false;
                System.out.println("|               |---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+");
                System.out.print("|               | Random 2      |");
                System.out.println(mergeSort(duplicateLists[3]));
                System.out.println("|               |---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+");
                System.out.print("|               | Partial Order |");
                System.out.println(mergeSort(duplicateLists[4]));
                System.out.println("+===============+===============+===============+===============+===============+");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.print("|               | In order      |");
                System.out.println(quicksort(duplicateLists[0]));
                System.out.println("|               |---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+");
                System.out.print("|               | Reverse Order |");
                System.out.println(quicksort(duplicateLists[1]));
                System.out.println("|               |---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+");
                System.out.print("|   QUICKSORT   | Random 1      |");
                System.out.println(quicksort(duplicateLists[2]));
                System.out.println("|               |---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+");
                System.out.print("|               | Random 2      |");
                System.out.println(quicksort(duplicateLists[3]));
                System.out.println("|               |---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+");
                System.out.print("|               | Partial Order |");
                System.out.println(quicksort(duplicateLists[4]));
                System.out.println("+===============+===============+===============+===============+===============+");
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("CALLS: " + calls); //testing only
    }


    private ArrayList<Integer> createList(String path) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        BufferedReader rd;
        try {
            rd = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                list.add(new Integer(Integer.parseInt(line)));
            }
            rd.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) { 
        }
        return list;
    }


    private <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Data selectionSort(List<T> l) {
        int compares = 0;
        int swaps = 0;
        double time = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < l.size()-1; ++i) {
            int minIndex = i;
            for (int j = i+1; j < l.size(); ++j) {
                if (l.get(j).compareTo(l.get(minIndex)) < 0) {
                    minIndex = j;
                }
                ++compares;
            }
            if (minIndex != i) {
                swap(l, minIndex, i);
                ++swaps;
            }
        }
        time = (System.nanoTime() - time)/Math.pow(10, 9); // convert to seconds
        return new Data(l, time, compares, swaps, "Selection");
    } // method selectionSort


    private <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Data insertionSort(List<T> l) {
        int compares = 0;
        int swaps = 0;
        double time = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 1; i < l.size(); ++i) {
            for (int j = i; j > 0 && l.get(j-1).compareTo(l.get(j)) > 0; --j) {
                ++compares; // once during every loop
                swap(l, j, j-1);
                ++swaps;
            }
            ++compares; // one to correspond to final check
        }
        time = (System.nanoTime() - time)/Math.pow(10, 9); // convert to seconds
        return new Data(l, time, compares, swaps, "Insertion");
    } // method insertionSort


    private <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Data bubbleSort(List<T> l) {
        int compares = 0;
        int swaps = 0;
        double time = System.nanoTime();

        int finalIndex = l.size()-1;
        int swapIndex;

        while (finalIndex > 0) {
            swapIndex = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < finalIndex; ++i) {
                if (((T)l.get(i)).compareTo(l.get(i+1)) > 0) { // if l[i] > l[i+1]
                    swap(l, i, i+1);
                    swapIndex = i;
                    ++swaps;
                }
                ++compares;
            }
            finalIndex = swapIndex;
        }
        time = (System.nanoTime() - time)/Math.pow(10, 9); // convert to seconds
        return new Data(l, time, compares, swaps, "Bubble");
    } // method bubbleSort


    private <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Data mergeSort(List<T> l) {
        double time = System.nanoTime();

        List<T> aux = (List<T>) ((ArrayList) l).clone();
        int compares = mergeSort(aux, l, 0, l.size());

        time = (System.nanoTime() - time)/Math.pow(10, 9); // convert to seconds
        return new Data(l, time, compares, 0, "Merge");
    } // method mergeSort 1 param


    private <T extends Comparable<? super T>> int mergeSort(List<T> src, List<T> dest, int low, int high) {

        if (flag) {
            calls++; // testing only
            System.out.println("PRE     SRC:  " + src);
            System.out.println("PRE     DEST: " + dest);
        }


        int compares = 0;

        int mid = (low + high) >> 1;
        if (high - low == 1) {

        } else {
            mergeSort(dest, src, 0, mid);
            mergeSort(dest, src, mid, high);
        }       
        for (int i = low, p = low, q = mid; i < high; ++i) {
            if (q >= high) {
                dest.set(i, src.get(p++));
            } else if (p >= mid){
                dest.set(i, src.get(q++));
            } else {
                if (((T)src.get(p)).compareTo(src.get(q)) <= 0) { 
                    dest.set(i, src.get(p++));
                } else {
                    dest.set(i, src.get(q++));
                }
                ++compares;
            }
        }


        if (flag) {
            System.out.println("POST    SRC:  " + src);
            System.out.println("POST    DEST: " + dest);
        }
        return compares;
    } // method mergeSort 4 params


    private <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Data quicksort(List<T> l) {

        return null;
    } // method quicksort


    private <T> void swap(List<T> l, int index1, int index2) {
        T temp = l.get(index1);
        l.set(index1, l.get(index2));
        l.set(index2, temp);
    } // method swap


    private void printHeaders() {
        System.out.println("+===============+===============+===============+===============+===============+\n" +
                            "|               |               |     TIME      |    NUMBER     |     NUMBER    |\n" +
                            "|  SORT METHOD  |  WHICH ARRAY  |      TO       |      OF       |       OF      |\n" +
                            "|               |               |   COMPLETE    |   COMPARES    |     SWAPS     |\n" +
                            "+===============+===============+===============+===============+===============+" );
    }


    private void createLists() {
        lists[0] = createList("C:\\Users\\Jason\\Documents\\School\\College\\Individual Studies\\202Projects\\07\\order.txt");
        lists[1] = createList("C:\\Users\\Jason\\Documents\\School\\College\\Individual Studies\\202Projects\\07\\reverse.txt");
        lists[2] = createList("C:\\Users\\Jason\\Documents\\School\\College\\Individual Studies\\202Projects\\07\\random1.txt");
        lists[3] = createList("C:\\Users\\Jason\\Documents\\School\\College\\Individual Studies\\202Projects\\07\\random2.txt");
        lists[4] = createList("C:\\Users\\Jason\\Documents\\School\\College\\Individual Studies\\202Projects\\07\\partial.txt");
    }


    private void resetDuplicates() {
        for (int i = 0; i < duplicateLists.length; i++) {
            if (duplicateLists[i] != null) {
                duplicateLists[i].clear();
            } else {
                duplicateLists[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < lists[i].size(); j++) {
                duplicateLists[i].add(new Integer(lists[i].get(j)));
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Data Class:

```
import java.util.List;


public class Data {
    private List list;
    private double time;
    private int compares;
    private int swaps;
    private String name;


    public Data(List list, double time, int compares, int swaps, String name) {
        this.list = list;
        this.time = time;
        this.compares = compares;
        this.swaps = swaps;
        this.name = name;
    }


    public List getList() {
        return list;
    }


    public double getTime() {
        return time;
    }


    public int getCompares() {
        return compares;
    }


    public int getSwaps() {
        return swaps;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public String toString() {
        String timeString = String.format("%-14.4f", time);
        String compareString = String.format("%-14d", compares);
        String swapString = String.format("%-14d", swaps);

        return " " + timeString + "| " + compareString + "| " + swapString + "| " + list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not because of your java code. Expression tab will show the value of the variable.

But the debug pointer is in the first line of your class and no such variable are even exist right now.

You proceed with the debugging, once you cross the line of code which creates the variable, then you will get to see the value there in expression viewm

Comment: This is not the case. The variables exist as can be seen in the variable pane in the image. I have tried further execution and it does not change.

Comment: Interesting... Then probably it must be a bug in eclipse. May be eclipse couldn't handle the method because of generics... Did you add generics to that method recently???